# Bidirectional @OneToMany and @ManyToOne - what`s the right way to remove child from collection without removing from database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Suppose I have two mapped entities, Field and Cluster. I would like to remove from Field one of mapped Clusters without deleting this Cluster from database. What`s the best way to do it?

Field.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "field")
public class Field extends Base {

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "field", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Cluster> clusters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Cluster.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cluster")
public class Cluster extends Base {
....
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "field_id")
private Field field;
```

Now I have to do something like that:

```
public FieldOutDto save(FieldInDto createRequest) {
    Field newField = new Field();
    modelMapper.map(createRequest, newField);
    setClusters(newField, createRequest);
    return modelMapper.map(fieldRepository.save(newField), FieldOutDto.class);
}

public FieldOutDto update(String id, FieldInDto updateRequest) {
    Field fromDb = fieldRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    modelMapper.map(updateRequest, fromDb);
    clusterRepository.findAllByField_Id(UUID.fromString(id)).forEach(cluster -> cluster.setField(null));
    setClusters(fromDb, updateRequest);
    return modelMapper.map(fieldRepository.save(fromDb), FieldOutDto.class);
}

public void delete(String id) {
    findById(id).getClusters()
            .forEach(cluster -> cluster.setField(null));
    fieldRepository.deleteById(UUID.fromString(id));
}

private void setClusters(Field field, FieldInDto request) {
    if (request.getClustersUuid() != null && !request.getClustersUuid().isEmpty()) {
        field.setClusters(request.getClustersUuid().stream()
                .map(id -> {
                    Cluster cluster = clusterRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
                    cluster.setField(field);
                    return cluster;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    } else {
        field.setClusters(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    }
}
```

I try to find a way to get the same result without it in UPDATE

```
clusterRepository.findAllByField_Id(UUID.fromString(id)).forEach(cluster -> cluster.setField(null));
```

and in DELETE methods

```
findById(id).getClusters()
           .forEach(cluster -> cluster.setField(null));
```

Comment: Ummm... `UPDATE Cluster c SET c.field = NULL WHERE c.field.id = :id`? Unless I misunderstood, that's what you're asking

Comment: Since you used the `spring` tag, if you're using Spring Data JPA, use this query with `@Query(modifying = true)`; otherwise, just use `EntityManager.createQuery(...).executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to remove a child from collection without removing from the database is by creating utility methods to add or remove children(Clusters) in your Parent(Field) class as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "field")
public class Field extends Base {

  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "field", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Cluster> clusters = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addCluster(Cluster cluster) {
    cluster.add(cluster);
    cluster.setField(this);
  }

  public void removeCluster(Cluster cluster) {
    cluster.remove(cluster);
    cluster.setField(null);
  }
}
```

Then you call these methods to add or remove a child(cluster) from the parent(Field) without deleting it from DB in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the the second line of the methods (addCluster, removeCluster) use the cluster object instead of clusters.

Comment: @Jalil.Jarjanazy Yes, Thanks for pointing out. Updated the code snippet.